# Identifying the configuration run through eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, configuration, macros, printf

I'm trying to print results file that contains all the information regarding the test that has just been implemented.

What i want to know is how do I identify the configuration run

```
fprintf(fp, "The DATE is :%s\n",__DATE__);
fprintf(fp, "The TIME is :%s\n",__TIME__);
fprintf(fp, "The RUN is  :%s\n",__???__);
```

see picture for further explanation  - [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwxsX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Project properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Symbols` tab. Choose a configuration on top. Then add a symbol named, say `RUN`. Then assign it a unique value. Then switch to another configuration and add the same symbol `RUN` with a different value. Now you can use the symbol in you program and it will have different values in different configuration.

** This will work for CDT managed build. Won't work for Makefile projects. In Makefile projects you will have to pass different flags to `make` in each configuration.